# oh-my-zsh history date formatting

Tags: linux, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to format oh-my-zsh history output.
It seems like `fc` is the way to go, since `history` ignores any settings in `HISTFILE`, `HISTSIZE` or `HISTTIMEFORMAT`

Is there a way to format it like I do with `date`

I can't find any proper documentation about the `fc` command online. there are also no man pages about `fc`.

what does work is `fc -flE` to output the history with a kind of european format.

In the end, what I want to do is to find out how many commands I typed today and when.

There is a little problem there.

**Currently I have this setup:**

`alias today='date +"%d.%m.%Y"'`
There is no format token that lets me remove leading zeros (I want 6 instead of 06)

But I have more format options here than with the weird zsh history command fc.
The history outputs the dates as 22.6.2016, and `today` is 22.06.2016
Hence, I can't do this:
`fc -flE | grep $(today) | wc -l`

Any feedback is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short answer:

```
fc -li | grep $(date -I)
```

The option `-i` instructs `fc` to print time stamps in ISO 8601 `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM` format. The `-I` option instructs date to output the date in ISO 8601 format (without time).

---

## As for the issues you encountered:

1. As `fc` is a builtin of `zsh` you can find its documentation in the [`zshbuiltin` manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands).
2. The options `-f` (print time stamps in US `MM/DD/YY hh:mm` format)  and `-E` (print time stamps in the European `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm` format)  are mutually exclusive, with `-E` taking precedence (silently, without error message). If you do not want the European format, drop the `-E` option.
3. You can explicitly specify the time stamp format for `fc` with the option `-t fmt`. The following will print time stamps like `06/22/2016 - 23:07:09` (note the zero padding):

   ```
   fc -lt '%m/%d/%Y - %H:%M:%S'
   ```

   This uses the `strftime` function (more info with `man 3 strftime`) to format the time stamp. So the format options are nearly identical to those you can use with `date`.
4. You can tell `date` not to pad a field by using the `-` flag. For example `6/22/16`:

   ```
   date +%-m/%-d/%y
   ```

   This flag also works for `fc`.

---

## Slightly longer answer:

If you prefer some other time stamp format than ISO 8601, you can just specify one an use it for both `date` and `fc`. For example: non-padded US date format and 0-padded clock time with seconds:

```
TS_DATE="%-m/%-d/%y"
TS_TIME="%H:%M:%S"
fc -lt "$TS_DATE $TS_TIME" | grep $(date +$TS_DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really difficult to find information about this command.
Thanks for your time and effort. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: I've been using oh-my-zsh for a few years now and I needed to get the latest [.zshrc template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/templates/zshrc.zsh-template) to get the `HIST_STAMPS` option. Maybe other people will have the same issue.